# Powershell copy file from Remote computer in a Docker Container to local machine

Tags: powershell, docker

I know this question has been asked in a variety of formats, but not QUITE my situation, so I'm asking it again (sorry)...

I have a Docker environment on my Windows 10 machine.  There is a file on the remote Docker "server" that I want to copy to my local Windows machine.

I can open a remote prompt to my Docker Container and the file 'OrderConfTest.pdf' is there:

[CSERVER]: PS C:> dir

Directory: C:\
Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
d-----         2/5/2020  12:05 PM                databases

d-----         2/5/2020  12:05 PM                driversetc

d-----        1/23/2020  10:59 AM                git

d-----        1/22/2020   3:33 PM                driversetc

d-----         2/5/2020  12:05 PM                host

d-----        3/10/2019   9:54 AM                inetpub

d-r---        3/10/2019  12:28 PM                Program Files

d-----        3/10/2019  12:28 PM                Program Files (x86)

d-----         2/5/2020  12:05 PM                Run

d-----        3/10/2019  12:28 PM                Test Assemblies

d-----        1/23/2020  12:53 PM                TestToolKit

d-----        3/10/2019   7:39 PM                UpgradeToolKit

d-r---        3/10/2019   9:54 AM                Users

d-----         2/5/2020  12:06 PM                Windows

-a----         2/6/2020   9:38 AM          22470 OrderConfTest.pdf

My local machine name is LAMIS-RS-A91

I am then entering this command:
[CSERVER]: PS C:> Copy-Item "C:\OrderConfTest.pdf" -Destination "\LAMIS-RS-A91\c$\"

Result is:

The network path was not found

```
+ CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Copy-Item], IOException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.IO.IOException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.CopyItemCommand
```

I also tried
 Copy-Item -path "C:\OrderConfTest.pdf" -Destination "\LAMIS-RS-A91\c$\"

Copy-Item -path "C:\OrderConfTest.pdf" -Destination "\LAMIS-RS-A91\c$"
 Copy-Item "C:\OrderConfTest.pdf" -Destination "\LAMIS-RS-A91\c$"

Any ideas or suggestions, anyone?

Thanks

Ron

Answer (score 0):

Instead of copy item, can you try [robocopy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/robocopy) command? robocopy has powerful than using existing cmdlet in PS.

```
SET _source="C:\OrderConfTest.pdf"
SET _dest="\\LAMIS-RS-A91\c$"

ROBOCOPY %_source% %_dest%
```